# How to manage the interactions in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pqwX.jpg)Having some trouble managing interactions between slicers and graphs in PowerBI.

1. I have filter for different Mock test(using slicer) and graphs for consolidated report and sectionwise report but when we select particular Mock Test eg: Mock test 1 Only the consolidated report will display the mock test 1 but in section wise it will display all the mock test  Can you please help?
2. And i have given edit interactions in format section as filter [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbvvX.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

First select the slicer. You will see a new format tab in the ribbon. Select edit interactions.
[image: This is how it looks]

You will get the two icons for each chart in the sheet. Clicking on that circle icon makes the filter interaction on or off for that chart.If you see my filter in the sheet is only applicable to two bar charts and not for the table chart. Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the solution but still i have given the filter option still it is not filtering

Comment: The table used for filter and table used for the other plots where you want filter to get applied shud be connected in the data model. Go to the modelling pane and see whether there is any relation between the two tables